# When i try to use an image that is in an array i get "the provided value is not of type"

Tags: javascript

When i run this code it throws an error but the images still work, is there a way to make it so that it doesn't throw an error. Also if i put an actual number in images[] it still works but if i put a variable that is a number in there it doesn't like if i do this images[1] it works but if i do this images[i] it doesn't even though that they are the same value

```
function getInventory () {
  console.log("Your inventory")

  for (var i in inventory) {
    console.log(i)

    if (i < 5) {
      Slot(i * 64, 0, 64, 64, images[i], 0, 0, 'red', false, 'itemSlot', Math.random())
    }
    if (i >= 5) {
      Slot((i - 5) * 64, 64, 64, 64, images[i], 0, 0, 'red', false, 'itemSlot', Math.random())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `inventory` coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its best to use a for loop not a for/in when using with an array

"Although it may be tempting to use this as a way to iterate over Array elements, the for...in statement will return the name of your user-defined properties in addition to the numeric indexes. Thus it is better to use a traditional for loop with a numeric index when iterating over arrays, because the for...in statement iterates over user-defined properties in addition to the array elements, if you modify the Array object, such as adding custom properties or methods."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I can not comment.

Comment: `var inventory = [1,2,3,4,3]` that's inventory it's literally just an array of numbers